# Testing components of the asynchronous work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-runtime, mstest, winrt-async

We have components encapsulates asynchronous logic. Now my question is, how can I test this, since my assert's time to run properly but honest too early?

Give it something like a global on-all-Thread's-wait command?

How you do go about it?

I Use MS Test, for example:

```
target = new MainViewModel(MOCK.GetDataService()); // The Magic asynchronous logic
lock (this) { Monitor.Wait(this, 50); } // my stupid solution
Assert.AreEqual(10, target.Count); // Assert
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are trying to unit test?

Comment: Which unit test framework are you using? MsTest, nUnit or xUnit?

Comment: I use MS Test, mompl. Code follows ....